# Awk to remove extra space after first letter?

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, gawk

Awk to remove extra space after first letter?

> Our file contains:

```
Blue    sky.    Nice       weather.
    White cloud.    Bright    sun.
        Cool air. Bla    bla          bla.
```

> How to have the content like this:

```
Blue sky. Nice weather.
    White cloud. Bright sun.
        Cool air. Bla bla bla.
```

This command, `awk '{$1=$1} 1' file`, removes all extra spaces.
But we only need to remove extra space after first letter.

Anyone know?
We appreciate all your attention!

Comment: After the first word, you mean?

Comment: Yes. We need remove extra spaces after first word. Thanks!

Comment: Do you need `awk` specifically? This `sed` would do it: `sed -r 's/([^ ]+) +/\1 /' file`.

Comment: @PesaThe, look at the example more carefully.  Your command won't do it.

Comment: @Wildcard ohhh, I understood it wrong and didn't check the whole output, sorry :)

Comment: @Wildcard, but adding `/g` should make it work, no? Though it might be better to use `[[:space:]]` instead of just the space, just in case there are tabs in the middle, etc.

Comment: @ilkkachu, I do believe you're right.  Huh.  Odd that I missed that; somehow I was thinking there would be match overlaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk you can do:

```
awk '{match($0,/(^[ ]+)/,arr)}; {$1=$1;printf("%s%s\n", arr[1], $0)}'
```

`match($0, /(^[ ]+)/, arr)` Capture the line leading spaces.
`$1=$1` remove all leading and repeated spaces.
`printf("%s%s\n", a[1], $0)}` re-add leading spaces and print.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running Linux and have GNU Sed, you can use the `g` flag along with a number to the `s`ubstitute command:

```
sed -r 's/ +/ /g2' file.txt
```

To quote `info sed`:

```
 Note: the POSIX standard does not specify what should happen when
 you mix the `g' and NUMBER modifiers, and currently there is no
 widely agreed upon meaning across `sed' implementations.  For GNU
 `sed', the interaction is defined to be: ignore matches before the
 NUMBERth, and then match and replace all matches from the NUMBERth
 on.
```

But since in one case you DO want to make the replacement on the first instance of a space (when there are no leading spaces), the full answer (with GNU Sed) is:

```
sed -r 's/^/ /;s/ +/ /g2;s/^ //' file.txt
```

In other words, add a leading space to all lines, then "squeeze" all instances of consecutive spaces except the first, then remove the added leading space.

---

If your leading spaces are always a multiple of 8, then you could instead use the following POSIX compliant command:

```
unexpand file.txt | sed 's/  */ /g' | expand
```

Or more simply:

```
unexpand file.txt | tr -s ' ' | expand
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a KISS way to do it in `awk`, I think:

```
{tmp = substr($0,1,match($0,/[^ \t]/)-1); $1=$1; print tmp""$0}
```

Ex.

```
$ awk '{tmp = substr($0,1,match($0,/[^ \t]/)-1); $1=$1; print tmp""$0}' file
Blue sky. Nice weather.
    White cloud. Bright sun.
        Cool air. Bla bla bla.
```

Comment: You are one of the important person of this world! Thanks for your time!